# Photoshop Loupe Function?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, tools

Don't ask why BUT after all this time, I realized this guy using a "Loupe" tool throughout his tutorial. Is there such a tool/plugin within Photoshop or is this most likely done in post?  I hate asking such question but it's like a bad itch.  ;)

[image]

Comment: What guy? Is this on static images? Video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that is a third party Mac app called [Zoom it](http://www.zoomitapp.com/).

[image]

---

---

I thought I'd also point out that this is a built in thing in both Mac and Windows. Just a bit different looking.

- **Mac:** [`Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom`](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph11488?locale=en_US)
- **Windows** [`Settings > Ease of Access > Magnifier`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier)

Comment: Except the screenshot looks to be Windows

Comment: You super sure about that @Ryan? Nothing there looks specifically like Windows Photoshop to me. I'm like 99,9% positive it is Zoom It on a mac. It totally looks like he is holding down `Ctrl+Z` to temporarily show the loupe, since it's showing that specific cursor...

Comment: Nope, not sure at all. You're probably right. I upvoted you either way.

Comment: @Joonas Yup, that's it!  Thank you, Sir. I can usually find these things but it was driving me nuts, especially because I can use this utility day to day.  You're the best!

Comment: @RadLexus  Thank you for the reminder and link, so kind of you.  I accidently did not select the "check mark".  Just a human being and work in progress.  ;)

Comment: @ErickP: thanks :) There are so many questions here with some very good answers – but not one accepted. And that persistent Community bot just keeps pushing them to the front page.